# Spring Data - MongoDb - What's happen if i update twice the same document

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using SpringBoot 2.1.10 and SpringData with MongoDB 3.6.2.

I have a `@Service` class with following business logic for reserve a generic voucher Document:

```
public Voucher reserveVoucher() {
     Voucher voucherToReserve = voucherRepository.findFirstByStatusEquals(VoucherStatus.ACTIVE)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new BadRequestException("VOUCHER_NOT_FOUND", "Voucher with status ACTIVE not found"));

     voucherToBeConsume.setStatus(VoucherStatus.RESERVED);
     voucherToBeConsume.setUserId(voucherConsumer.getUserId());

     return voucherRepository.save(voucherToBeConsume);
}
```

I Know that `@Service` classes in Spring is `Singleton` by Default.
What's happen in an environment with more servers if `findFirstByStatusEquals` method retrieve the same Document and after `save` method is executed twice? The Document is updated twice or the second update fails?

Comment: [Read Isolation, Consistency, and Recency](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/)

Answer (score 1):

Even on one server, the service can be called by two different threads at the same time, e.g. via 2 concurrent REST calls.

In MongoDB you can't use row locks like SELECT ... FOR UPDATE in transactional databases.
So in your case, the document will possibly be updated twice.

You can emulate row locks however via a conditional update:

```
UpdateResult updateResult = mongoTemplate.updateFirst(
  query(
    where("_id").is(voucherToReserve.getId())
     .and("status").is(VoucherStatus.ACTIVE)
  ), 
  new Update()
    .set("status", VoucherStatus.RESERVED)
    .set("userId", userId),
  Voucher.class
);  
if(updateResult.getModifiedCount() != 1){
  throw ...
}
```

See also https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/how-to-select--for-update-inside-mongodb-transactions

Comment: Thanks so much for clearing my doubt, your suggestion it works well!